# Displaying custom selected dates from db in JQuery multiple calendars on the page

Tags: jquery, calendar

I am working on a login system where user can register multiple products with availability calenders attached to them. Whole site works on ajax response.

Problem is that when a user select a uploaded product first time and view the calender, previously saved dates displays alright as selected. But after that not matter how many products he switches to, it keeps showing same dates data on calendar.

Below is my code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

// Click Function On Calendar Tab
$("#tabCalendar").click(function(){
    var productId = $("#productId").val();
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'../ajax/listing_availabily_dates_fetch.php',
        data: "&productId=" + productId,
        datatype: 'json',
        success:function(response){
            startTheCalendar(response);
        }
    });
});

function startTheCalendar(response){
    $("#show-next-month").calendar({
        num_next_month: 11,
        num_prev_month: 0,
        unavailable: response, // This is where dates should update
        onSelectDate: function(date, month, year, thisEvent){
            var dateData = [year, month, date].join('-');
            selected = response;
            dateClickEvent(dateData, thisEvent);
        }
    });
}

// function dateClickEvent(dateData, thisEvent) {}


});
```

Looking for help.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for the solution in wrong direction, or may be more complicated one. I thought it would be easier if I could refresh plugin data, for which I even started creating a custom function in plugin itself.

To my surprise and in absence of any help, it was fairly easy:

HTML:

```
<div id="calendar-holder">
    <div id="calendar" ></div>
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
function startTheCalendar(response){

    $("#calendar-holder").html("");
    $("#calendar-holder").html('<div id="calendar" ></div>');

    if(response == ""){ response = []; }

    $("#show-next-month").calendar({
        num_next_month: 11,
        num_prev_month: 0,
        unavailable: response, // This is where dates should update
        onSelectDate: function(date, month, year, thisEvent){
            var dateData = [year, month, date].join('-');
            selected = response;
            dateClickEvent(dateData, thisEvent);
        }
    });
}
```

I just had to clear the plugin data from HTML and repopulate it.